# How to dd the value in database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-request

I want to check the value in the database whether it is the same with the form value. How can I view the value in database using dd syntex?

```
dd('status');

$updateForm = Form::where('reference_no',$r->refer)
    -> update([
    'status' => $r->sts,
    'reference_no' => $r->refer,
    'task' => $r->tsk, 
    'receiver' => $r->to,
    'rider' => $r->frm,
  ]);
```

Comment: try this way dd($request->post('status')); if you are sending data using post method

Comment: Hello @Amir Nasir, please provide more detail of eloquent model and what you actually want.

Comment: Basically I just want to know whether the database value is updated or not by using dd. I already solve it thanks to @Luka Peharda. Anyway thanks guys for responding. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do an `update` it returns number of rows affected/updated. It won't return DB rows that were updated.

So you need to fetch the data from DB and show that:

```
$numberOfRowsUpdated = Form::where('reference_no', $r->refer)
    -> update([
        'status' => $r->sts,
        'reference_no' => $r->refer,
        'task' => $r->tsk, 
        'receiver' => $r->to,
        'rider' => $r->frm,
    ]);

// This will get you the first form with given "reference_no"
$updatedForm = Form::where('reference_no', $r->refer)->first();
dd($updatedForm->status);

// If you are updating multiple rows and dump all its items and attributes
$updatedForms = Form::where('reference_no', $r->refer)->get();
dd($updatedForms);
```

Maybe this will help and you can proceed from here.